# BBCode на самописку

Tags: php, cms, bbcode

Нужен BBCode на самописную CMS, в интернете не смог найти ничего стоящего, возможно, кто-то подкинет свой скрипт или же ткнет на готовый...
Нужна примерно такая форма, как на этом сайте при добавлении вопроса. ))
Думаю, высказался, жду ответов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[тык](http://forums.codecharge.com/posts.php?post_id=77123)

Comment: спс буду чинить )

Answer (score 0):

Знакомая проблема, где то месяц назад потралил 4 дня на поиски и подбор подходящего для меня BBCode визивиг редактора) свой выбор я остановил на tiny mce, при этому на simple варианте.

По причине не громоздкого размера и минимума функций. Ну а так, в принципе, можно сделать почти MS Word))

Так к чему это я... а да... посоветовать тебе можно около 30 редакторов почти 1 ссылкой, но выберешь ты всё равно один. "тут нет этого" "этот слишком тяжело переделать под себя" "еще 1000 и одна причина" :)

Comment: tiny mce и ckeditor не являются редакторами BB-тэгов. Это именно что wysiWyg редакторы.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/bbcode

Comment: очь мудро, я помоему готовое просил.